# Percentage calculation always returns me 0 even that the values are numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integer-division

I'm trying to create a percentage for some errors in my table.
I build a query that brings the qty of errors per each value, the total errors, and the division.
But is always giving me 0 (I added a check in order to see if the values are numeric) .

```
select 
ZZ0010 as Error_type
, qty
, total
,running_sum
, isnumeric(total)
,isnumeric(running_sum)
,running_sum/total

from (
    select ZZ0010
            ,(count(  [ZZ0010] )) as qty
             ,sum(nullif(count(  [ZZ0010] ),0) ) over(order by count(  [ZZ0010] )  desc,ZZ0010) as running_sum 
             ,sum(nullif(count(  [ZZ0010] ),0) ) over() as total
    from md.CAR_CRM_DS_ZCRM_Z101_BUSINESS_ATTR_VT   
    group by ZZ0010
    having (count(  [ZZ0010] )) is not null 
                                                ) tbl
order by running_sum asc
```

| Error_type | qty | total | running_sum | isnumeric(total) | isnumeric(running_sum) | running_sum/total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2123 | 3931 | 2123 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 1808 | 3931 | 3931 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Integer division. Multiply by `1.0` to change it to decimals  `running_sum * 1.0 / total`

Comment: U are right! so simple solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you can radically simplify this:

```
select ZZ0010,
       count(*) as qty,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by count(*) desc) as running_sum,
       sum(count(*)) over () as total,
       ( sum(count(*)) over (order by count(*) desc) * 1.0 /
         nullif(sum(count(*)) over (), 0)
       ) as ratio
from md.CAR_CRM_DS_ZCRM_Z101_BUSINESS_ATTR_VT   
group by ZZ0010;
```

Notes:

- I don't know why you would use `isnumeric()` on number columns.
- `COUNT()` cannot return `NULL` so the `HAVING` is redundant.
- Use `NULLIF()` to avoid division by `0`.  Of course, the sum of counts cannot be zero in your query unless all rows have `ZZ0010` as `NULL`.
- SQL Server does integer division.  I just multiply by `1.0` to avoid this.
- `NULLIF(COUNT(), 0)` is just really strange.  Why distinguish  between `0` and `NULL` in a column that ignores nulls?
- I don't think a subquery is particularly useful in this case, but if you don't want to repeat the expressions, you can certainly use a subquery.